# It is a good practice multiply by a boolean on javascript?

Tags: javascript

Javascript allow using a boolean on arithmetic expressions but I want to know if is a good practice to do so.

For example:

```
var expectedGuests = 100 * ((day==='Friday')*1.5 || 1);
```

I know this can be written in different ways but I want to know if using this means a negative or maybe positive impact on performance, navigator compatibility or any other important matter that I should be aware of.

Comment: `var expectedGuests = 100 * (day === 'Friday' ? 1.5 : 1);`

Comment: A ternary expression like @tymeJV's is definitely the way to go. I see you added a mention of performance impact. A calculation that small is such a minor detail that I wouldn't worry about it. [80:20 rule applies](http://swreflections.blogspot.com/2013/11/applying-8020-rule-in-software.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a ternary, it'll be cleaner:

```
var multiplier = day === 'Friday' ? 1.5 : 1;
var expectedGuests = 100 * multiplier;
```